# What is the stochastic process: "Bernoulli" process with non-binary output?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference

In my modelling, I am considering a stochastic process quite like the Bernoulli process but with output variable $y\in[0,1]$ (i.e., a probabilistic outcome, rather than binary $\{0,1\}$ outcome). I guess there should be a well studied stochastic process modelling this, if yes then what it is? E.g., named after some guy with publications and application examples

For now, as a backup plan but not ideal, what I can think of is to use categorical distribution for the output variable $y$ by discretising $y$ into several categories... Thanks for your time.

Comment: Perhaps the uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$ is what you seek? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution

Comment: Sorry for being slow, then how to write down the likelihood seeing a sequence of outcomes and what are the varibles in that likelihood function...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you know the density (which is specified in the link), then it is straightforward to derive the likelihood function. The parameters in the likelihood function are the parameters in the density. What outcomes are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks for the reply. I need to think of the physical meaning of those paramters in my case...

Comment: Ohhh... well the parameters in the case of the uniform distribution do not mean that much, in the sense that they only tell you about the support of the distribution (which in your case is $[0, 1]$). If you want the parameters to influence the shape of the distribution, then perhaps the Beta distribution is more useful? It has support on $[0,1]$. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution